# my swift app crashes when incoming json is incomplete. How can I deal with it?

Tags: swift, swift3

In my Swift app, I'm downloading JSON with comments stored on my server. The webservice returns JSON with following fields:

- id
- username
- photo_url
- descr
- updated_at
- hashtags

To use that data and parse it correctly in the app I created a class `SingleComment`:

```
class SingleComment: NSObject {
    var id: String
    let username: String
    let photo_url: String
    var descr: String
    var updated_at: Date
    var hashtag: [String]


    init(id: String, username: String, photo_url: String, descr: String, updated_at: Date, hashtag: [String]) {
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.photo_url = photo_url
        self.descr = descr
        self.updated_at = updated_at
        self.hashtag = hashtag

        super.init()
    }

    class func fromJSON(_ json: JSON) -> SingleComment? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

        let id = json["_id"].string
        let username = json["username"].string
        let photo_url = json["photo_url"].string!
        let descr = json["text_content"].string
        let updated_at = json["updated_at"].string

        let upd = dateFormatter.date(from: updated_at!)

        let hashtag:[String] = json["hashtags"].arrayValue.map { $0.stringValue}

        return SingleComment(id: id!, username: username!, photo_url: photo_url!, descr: descr!, updated_at: upd!, hashtag: hashtag!)
    }
}
```

But the problem is that sometimes the json might miss some fields, then I'm getting error that says there was a `nil` object. How can I prevent it from happening? Currently my app crashes, so I think I should either provide default values or make sure that none of those fields are required.

What's the best strategy here?

Comment: check your data with if let

Comment: Did you try to use something like https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper ?

Comment: You can use if let ,guard ,explicit nil check,etc to prevent crahes.Go through below link for more info [Swift optionals ](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_optionals.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Make `SingleComment` properties optionals

```
 class SingleComment: NSObject {

 var id: String? // default they would be nil
let username: String?
let photo_url: String?
var descr: String?
var updated_at: Date?
var hashtag: [String]?


init(id: String? , username: String? , photo_url: String? , descr: String?, updated_at: Date?, hashtag: [String]?) {

    self.id = id
    self.username = username
    self.photo_url = photo_url
    self.descr = descr
    self.updated_at = updated_at
    self.hashtag = hashtag

    super.init()
}

class func fromJSON(_ json: JSON) -> SingleComment {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

    let id = json["_id"].string
    let username = json["username"].string
    let photo_url = json["photo_url"].string
    let descr = json["text_content"].string
    let updated_at = json["updated_at"].string

    let upd = dateFormatter.date(from: updated_at ?? "")

    let hashtag:[String] = json["hashtags"].arrayValue.map { $0.stringValue}

    return SingleComment(id: id, username: username, photo_url: photo_url, descr: descr, updated_at: upd, hashtag: hashtag)
}
```

}

and whenever use `SingleComment` properties. use it using `if let` construct.